# What causes water to change color?

Tags: terraria

In the 1.2 update, I've noticed that water will occasionally change color (this has been most notable for me in a few underground water pools). For example, one pool of water will occasionally turn from blue to orange and back again.

What, if anything, is controlling the water color changes? Is it biome specific (i.e. I'm moving between two different biomes and I don't realize it)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you see water changing colors, you are moving into a new biome.  For example, if you see a pool of water right between a Snow and Desert biome, you will see the water change from icey blue to muddy orange.  When you're underground, you could also be transitioning between layers.  This will be accompanied by a change in backgrounds.

Aside from that, water now turns red during a blood moon.

Comment: I can confirm this, as I've seen that example happen!